# Rails 4 IF check syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, if-statement

I am trying to make two checks again the database and I am getting method errors.

```
    <% if @person.subordinates.position.any == 'grad' %>
        <h3>Neuro Grads</h3>
        <table>
        CONTENT
        </table>
    <% end %>
```

And the second one is much of the same content but with a double check...

```
<% if @person.subordinates.position.any == 'nn-grad' or 'nn-postdoc' %>
```

In the first area I need to check if there are any `@person.subordinates.position` that are listed as `grad` in the database. In the second area, I need to check if it is either of the two positions.

Comment: Write errors, please

Comment: **undefined method `position' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>**

It is calling the line that I put in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `position` is just the association. Try to map it and use correct [Enumerable#any?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) syntax:

```
if @person.subordinates.map(&:position).any? {|p| p == 'grad'}
```

And:

```
if @person.subordinates.map(&:position)
                       .any? {|p| p == 'nn-grad' || p == 'nn-postdoc' }
```